# Multiple Layer of LSTM for Prediction using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I was following [this repo](https://github.com/BinRoot/TensorFlow-Book/tree/master/ch10_rnn) to work with time-series prediction using RNN. But in this repo, the test error was coming around 24%. So I was trying multi-layer LSTM model as method to improve the prediction accuracy. The code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
import data_loader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class SeriesPredictor(object):

    def __init__(self, input_dim, seq_size, lstm_size, num_layers=2):

        # Hyperparameters
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.seq_size = seq_size
        self.lstm_size = lstm_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        # Weight variables and input placeholders
        self.W_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([lstm_size, 1]), name='W_out')
        self.b_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name='b_out')
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, seq_size, input_dim])
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, seq_size])

        # Cost optimizer
        self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.model(2) - self.y))
        self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(self.cost)

        # Auxiliary ops
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver()

    def model(self, num_layers):
        """
        :param x: inputs of size [T, batch_size, input_size]
        :param W: matrix of fully-connected output layer weights
        :param b: vector of fully-connected output layer biases
        """
        cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.lstm_size)
        stacked_lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
            [tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell,
                                           output_keep_prob=0.8)
             for _ in range(num_layers)]
        )
        outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stacked_lstm_cell, self.x, dtype=tf.float32)
        num_examples = tf.shape(self.x)[0]
        W_repeated = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(self.W_out, 0), [num_examples, 1, 1])
        out = tf.matmul(outputs, W_repeated) + self.b_out
        out = tf.squeeze(out)
        return out

    def train(self, train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y):
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            max_patience = 3
            patience = max_patience
            min_test_err = float('inf')
            step = 0
            while patience > 0:
                _, train_err = sess.run([self.train_op, self.cost], feed_dict={
                    self.x: train_x, self.y: train_y})
                if step % 100 == 0:
                    test_err = sess.run(self.cost, feed_dict={self.x: test_x, self.y: test_y})
                    print('step: {}\t\ttrain err: {}\t\ttest err: {}'.format(step, train_err, test_err))
                    if test_err < min_test_err:
                        min_test_err = test_err
                        patience = max_patience
                    else:
                        patience -= 1
                step += 1
            save_path = self.saver.save(
                sess, 'model.ckpt')
            print('Model saved to {}'.format(save_path))

    def test(self, sess, test_x):
        tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
        self.saver.restore(sess, './model.ckpt')
        output = sess.run(self.model(2), feed_dict={self.x: test_x})
        return output

    def plot_results(train_x, predictions, actual, filename):
        plt.figure()
        num_train = len(train_x)
        plt.plot(list(range(num_train)), train_x, color='b', label='training data')
        plt.plot(list(range(num_train, num_train + len(predictions))),
                 predictions, color='r', label='predicted')
        plt.plot(list(range(num_train, num_train + len(actual))),
                 actual, color='g', label='test data')
        plt.legend()
        if filename is not None:
            plt.savefig(filename)
        else:
            plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    seq_size = 5
    predictor = SeriesPredictor(input_dim=1, seq_size=seq_size, lstm_size=100)
    data = data_loader.load_series('international-airline-passengers.csv')
    train_data, actual_vals = data_loader.split_data(data)

    train_x, train_y = [], []
    for i in range(len(train_data) - seq_size - 1):
        train_x.append(np.expand_dims(train_data[i:i + seq_size], axis=1).tolist())
        train_y.append(train_data[i + 1:i + seq_size + 1])

    test_x, test_y = [], []
    for i in range(len(actual_vals) - seq_size - 1):
        test_x.append(np.expand_dims(actual_vals[i:i + seq_size], axis=1).tolist())
        test_y.append(actual_vals[i + 1:i + seq_size + 1])

    predictor.train(train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        predicted_vals = predictor.test(sess, test_x)[:, 0]
        print('predicted_vals', np.shape(predicted_vals))
        plot_results(train_data, predicted_vals, actual_vals, 'predictions.png')

        prev_seq = train_x[-1]
        predicted_vals = []
        for i in range(20):
            next_seq = predictor.test(sess, [prev_seq])
            predicted_vals.append(next_seq[-1])
            prev_seq = np.vstack((prev_seq[1:], next_seq[-1]))
        plot_results(train_data, predicted_vals, actual_vals, 'hallucinations.png')
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> ValueError: Trying to share variable
>   rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel, but specified shape
>   (200, 400) and found shape (101, 400).

I'm trying to long to resolve the issue. But not getting the reason why. Can anyone please guide me why I'm getting this error?

Thank you!

Comment: Each layer of the Multilayer RNN should have a different layer so you have to call the BasicLSTMCell constructor as many times as the number of layers. Instead of 'cell', call rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.lstm_size) inside the DropoutWrapper.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: Thank you for your answer! It solved this problem. If you could explain why "cell" was not working (because "cell" is nothing but "rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.lstm_size)"). If you put that in the answer I'll mark it as answer. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `cell` is just one instance of the class `BasicLSTMCell`. You are using that same object in all the layers of the `MultiRNNCell`. Instead each layer should have a **different** object instance of the class `BasicLSTMCell`.

Therefore you should instantiate a separate instance for each layer by calling the constructor each time.

```
    stacked_lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.lstm_size),output_keep_prob=0.8) for _ in range(num_layers)] )
```

Comment: Thank you Abhishek!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.